# Google analytics integration suddenly shows no reporting data yet the real-time shows traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have been using Google analytics for awhile now.  It has been great for both live traffic and historical reporting.

Suddenly on Sept 5 our reporting shows zero traffic (using the standard reporting overview tab).

[image]

This seems really strange as you can see there is near constant traffic in the real-time tab.

Has anybody else experienced this problem when integrating Google analytics?  We had a filter that only traffic from our main domain (app.domain.com) would show.  Even after removing this we get nothing in the reports.

[image]

Comment: Yup .. having the same issue .. about 200 real time visitors .. 0 in standard reporting .. its happening since last couple of days ..

Comment: And all of sudden they are back now ... apparently this happens .. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/IfyS5DPai0c

Answer (score 3):

Check the filters on that profile. Go into Admin on the top right and check the Filters tab on the profile.

Filters are not applied to real time data.

So what you're seeing here is data being filtered out from the profile, but still showing up in the real time.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a few different things

1. A temporary glitch by Google - this happened to me (which is how I got to this page). I could see traffic in the real time view but nothing in reports. **To fix:** be patient - this resolved itself after about 12 hours.
2. profile issue - you may have a profile set up that has filters which are blocking more traffic than you were expecting. **To fix:** Try setting up a separate profile (if you don't have one already) that has no filters applied. Remember- profile filters work by stripping or manipulating traffic before they reach your reports. The answer above is incorrect- **the real time view does take filters in to account**. You can easily test this making a filter change and you'll see it take affect in the real time view
3. tag has dropped off your pages **To fix:** if you're using GTM you should be able to check this. Or if not check HTML page source on one of your pages you know is getting traffic
4. finally - you may not getting any traffic :)